# How to find position number of a certain child element in a parent element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, position, parent-child

I have a div containing several other divs containing an image. It looks smth like this

```
<div id="parentHldr">
 <div class="imgHldr"><img src="foo/bar.png" id="1"></div>
 <div class="imgHldr"><img src="foo/bar.png" id="2"></div>
 <div class="imgHldr"><img src="foo/bar.png" id="3"></div>
 <div class="imgHldr active"<img src="foo/bar.png" id="4"></div>
 <div class="imgHldr"><img src="foo/bar.png" id="5"></div>
 <div class="imgHldr"><img src="foo/bar.png" id="6"></div>
</div>
```

I want to know the position of div that has class active. I get total number of children elements with this thing

```
$('#parentHldr').children().length
```

So i presume, there should be a way of finding the positional number of that div somehow...

ok, i've practically found the solution. Now its a bit more complicated. I need to get index of a **DIV** w/ *class imgHldr* containing **img** with *id 5* inside the parent **DIV** w/ *class parentHldr*. Is this possible??))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$("#parentHldr > div").index($("#parentHldr > div.active"));
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks a lot, forgot to tag this as noob-question ;) GOD, I love stackoverflow!!