# find which child of parent element jquery

Tags: jquery

So I can find if an element is a child of a parent, but I can't figure out how to get the index of the current element in the parent element.  For example.  I have collapsing articles on my page http://gundlach-marketing.com/dev, in order to reset the margins I need to know what article number they are.

```
var articleId = $(this).attr('id');
var articleIndex;
$(this).parent().children('article').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == articleId) {articleIndex = index}
});
```

the above code works, It's just inelegant.  There has to be a better way! What is it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342376/how-to-find-position-number-of-a-certain-child-element-in-a-parent-element-using?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().children()
```

is equivalent to

```
$(this).siblings()
```

no? And

```
$(this).index()
```

might just do the job of both.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/VChu4/

Comment: wow. I assumed because the jquery object is often an array that with one active element $('.active').index() would always return 0.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `$ele.index`

```
var $this = $(this);
var articleId = $this.prop('id');
var $article = $this.find("#" + articleId);
var index = $this.siblings('article').index($article);
```

If you are trying to find the index of this then just use

```
var index $(this).parent().getChildren('articles').index(this);
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).parent(...).getSiblings is not a function

Comment: @BGundlach my bad bad copy paste